# get neighborhood of a node Arangodb

Tags: graph, filter, arangodb, neighbours

I'm trying to get the neighborhood of a node in ArangoDB.

When I do this to get IN nodes:

```
 for v in Protein_G_H
    filter v._to == "p2/9606.ENSP00000326759"
    return v
```

I get a result. Doing this to get OUT nodes

```
for v in Protein_G_H
    filter v._from == "p2/9606.ENSP00000326759"
    return v
```

I also get result but doing this:

```
for v in Protein_G_H
    filter v._to == "p2/9606.ENSP00000326759"
    filter v._from == "p1/9606.ENSP00000326759"
    return v
```

--or--

```
for v in Protein_G_H
    filter v._to == "p2/9606.ENSP00000326759"
      and v._from == "p1/9606.ENSP00000326759"
    return v
```

to get in and out nodes I get nothing. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve in **and** out nodes, you need to test if the `_from` **or** `_to` property of the edge is equal to the node you want to get the neighbors for:

```
for e in Protein_G_H
    filter e._to == "p2/9606.ENSP00000326759"
      or e._from == "p2/9606.ENSP00000326759"
    return e
```

I would recommend to use AQL graph traversal however to retrieve neighbor vertices:

```
for v in 1..1 any "p2/9606.ENSP00000326759" Protein_G_H
    return v
```

This will return first degree neighbor vertices of vertex `9606.ENSP00000326759` in the vertex collection `p2`, following the edges in edge collection `Protein_G_H` in any direction (either _from or _to must be equal to `p2/9606.ENSP00000326759`).